# Android: AnimationDrawable

Tags: android, animation, animationdrawable

```
I hope for the help. I create at first for ImageView TranslateAnimation, then as AnimationEnd I register creation of AnimationDrawable in ListenerAnimation and I start it.
ImageView MyImageView = New ImageView(this);
MyImageView.setImageResources(R.drawable.mypic1);
TranslateAnimation tr = New TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 50);
tr.setFillAfter(true);
tr.setDuration(3000);
```

MyImageView.startanimation(tr);
    But I see only the first shot. Then, if after that I create and I will start still any animation, for example, again TranslateAnimation, AnimationDrawable begin completely.
    AnimationDrawable ad = New AnimationDrawable();
    ad.setOneShot(true);
    ad.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mypic1), 500);
    ad.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mypic2), 500);
    ad.selectDrawable(0);
    MyImageView.setImageDrawable(ad);
    ad.start();
    What to make not to create after AnimationDrawable still Animation? In advance I thank for the help.